# MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError read error log - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play video files. Some movies are not playing. I just recieve MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError. But for some reasons I can't read error log.
Here is code:

```
 case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
    {
       NSLog(@"%@",moviePlayer.errorLog);
    }
break;
```

Error log is null. How to read Error log?

Comment: No, moviePlayer is initialized. For some reason ios doesn't want to play this video link 

http://cs13255.vkontakte.ru/u5078524/video/427f63b92d.240.mp4
I tryed to play this link from Safari browser. I received an error.

Comment: Is this video up on a local server or something because I tried to play it on my browser and it says server not found! What error did you get from safari?

Comment: I tried to play this video from my iPad 2's Safari. Safari says something like: movie can't be played. But on simulator it plays good.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are accessing the NSError object correctly? 
In case of an error, the notification contains an NSError object available using the @"error" key in the notification's userInfo dictionary. 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I will verify that grabbing the error in this manner worked for me.